# Local copy of event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, delegates

**Why do I need local copy of event here** (purpose of `myEvent`)?

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent = delegate {};

protected OnMyEvent()
{
    var myEvent = MyEvent;
    myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Imho, this is functionally similar to

```
protected OnMyEvent() => MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty)
```

**But I was told what local copy is essential**. And this is totally blow up my mind.

---

I agree *local copy* is a must in following scenario:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

protected OnMyEvent()
{
    var myEvent = MyEvent;
    if(myEvent != null)
        myEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Because between `null` check and invoking some other thread may unsubscribe and if it was the last subscriber then we will get `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: In your example, when you have default handler - you don't need. In common - you should copy to local variable

Comment: "But I was told what local copy is essential". You could have asked the question to the same person. Btw your code  below with local copy and null checks can also result in `NullReferenceException` (Refer ReadIntroduction part of [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx))

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I did ask him and got an impression like I don't know something what he and **everybody else** knows. Therefore a question ;)  `Read introduction` sounds like a compiler bug. Luckily we have c# now to just `MyEvent?.Invoke()`

Comment: AFAIK that local variable will get optimized. You'll effectively end up with `MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty)`. ReadIntroduction is a valid optimization(which scares me). Not a bug :)

Comment: No, that's the wrong view.  It won't use memory to store the local variable and gets optimized to use a CPU register.  But the load and the if() test are still there.  This is otherwise just a stoopid trick to avoid having to test for null, it will never be null.  Testing for null is a *lot* quicker than calling an empty method through a delegate.  Intentionally writing slow code is not a fantastic habit to acquire.  The odds that it actually makes a difference are rather low.  Until it does and you have no idea why your program is slow.

Comment: I don't think you need that local copy so point to some sort of source for this claim. Right now it's just dubious hearsay, not a real question.